# Add to Array-Form of Integer - how to show the full result?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, integer

Add to Array-Form of Integer : say I have `A=[1,2,3]`, `K = 50000`, I want to add those two and get `A=[5,0,1,2,3]`,

after I add them and convert the carry to list, but somehow I can not get the full array printed :

```
def addToArrayForm(A, K):
    A[-1] += K
    for i in range(len(A) - 1, -1, -1):
        carry, A[i] = divmod(A[i], 10)
        if i: A[i-1] += carry
    if carry:
        B=list(str(carry))
        A=B+A
        
    return A
  
A=[1,2,3]
addToArrayForm(A, 5000)
for i in range(len(A) ):
    print (A[i])
```

the result shows: `1,2,3` :
but I was expecting `5,0,1,2,3,` where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your original code is that the command `A = B+A` doesn't do what you apparently expect.  I'm not sure, because your function returns a given value (the new, updated `A`), but your main program assumes that the list is changed in place.

The value you return is the one you expect.  However, it is no longer the original object `A`.  The expression `B+A` builds a new list; your *local* variable `A` is changed to point to that and returned ... where your main program ignores it.

Make a simple change:

```
A=[1,2,3]
A = addToArrayForm(A, 50000)    # I corrected this to 50000; you were short a 0
```

Output:

```
5
0
1
2
3
```

---

MORE PROBLEMS

Note that this is not sustainable -- you can't do additional math on this list, because you've left the elements of `B` as string, rather than integer.  You'll want to convert those, I think.

---

ANOTHER WAY ...

If you *do* want to alter A in place, then try pushing those digits to the start of the list, *in place*:

```
...
    if carry:
        B = list(str(carry))
        for dig in B:
            A.insert(0, int(dig))

A=[1,2,3]
addToArrayForm(A, 50000)
...
```

Comment: thanks , it really fixed my code , but why we need "A= " in front of addToArrayForm(A, 50000)? I have specified the return value to be "A", after execute addToArrayForm(A, 50000), A should be an updated list ...

Comment: That's the second paragraph of my answer.  If you want to watch the effect, `print(id(A))` at strategic places within your function, as well as before and after the call in your main program.

Answer (score 1):

```
def add(a, k):
    return [int(j) for j in str(k + int(''.join(str(i) for i in a)))]
```

Example

```
>>> add([1,2,3], 50000)
[5, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by converting `A` to an integer, adding that to `K`, and then replacing `A` in-place with the sum, this should work regardless of the number of digits in `K` (or `A`).

```
def addToArrayForm(A, K):
    a = 0
    for d in A:
        a = a*10 + d
    A[:] = [int(d) for d in str(a + K)]
    return A

A = [1, 2, 3]

addToArrayForm(A, 50000)

for i in range(len(A)):
    print(A[i])
```

Output:

```
5
0
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def addToArrayForm(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        # convert the array form into a string    
        string=""
        for num in nums:
            string+=str(num)
        # add the values
        res=int(string)+k
        # res is an int but we cannot iterate over int. So we convert it to str
        return[int(x) for x in str(res)]
```